# ORA-02291 Integrity Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have tried everything but still getting an error inserting in data.

```
  create table Address(
  AddressID integer primary key,
  StreetnameID integer,
  CountyID integer,
  CityID integer,
  PostcodeID integer,
  DoornumID integer,
  foreign key (StreetnameID) references Streetname,
  foreign key (CountyID) references County,
  foreign key (CityID) references City,
  foreign key (PostcodeID) references Postcode,
  foreign key (DoornumID) references Doornum
);
```

This is my address creation table. Below is my insert statement that is failing.

```
INSERT INTO Address(AddressID, StreetnameID, CountyID, CityID, PostcodeID, DoornumID)
values(seq_AddressID.nextval, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue to generate this error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ROOT.SYS_C007211) violated - parent key not found
```

Comment: (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. So give the least code you can that is some code that you show is OK extended by some code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2):

One of the foreign key references does not exist.  They all must exist.  This would be easier to figure out if you named the constraints:

```
create table Address (
  AddressID integer primary key,
  StreetnameID integer,
  CountyID integer,
  CityID integer,
  PostcodeID integer,
  DoornumID integer,
  constraint fk_address_StreetnameID foreign key (StreetnameID) references Streetname,
  constraint fk_address_CountyID foreign key (CountyID) references County,
  constraint fk_address_CityID foreign key (CityID) references City,
  constraint fk_address_PostcodeID foreign key (PostcodeID) references Postcode,
  constraint fk_address_DoornumID foreign key (DoornumID) references Doornum
);
```

The constraint requires that the corresponding rows exist in the reference tables *before* you can insert the rows into `address`.

Answer (score 0):

**ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ROOT.SYS_C007211) violated - parent key not found**

For an insert statement, this ORA-02291 error is common when you are trying to insert a child without a matching parent, as defined by a foreign key constraint.  In that case, you need to add the parent row to the table and then re-insert your child table row.

so check your parent table where you missed to put data that are trying to insert here in current child table